# d3 function(d) return value from object not from the first index(0)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

why d3  function(d) return value from object not from the first index(0)

```
tr.append('td').html(function(m) { console.log(m.INDEX) ;return m.INDEX; })
```

from this function i have value from index 1 to m.INDEX.length 
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this statement you tell you want to update a `td` for each item `m` in an array `a` supplied by `tr.data(a)` and add a html containing `m.INDEX` to the updated `td`. When you want to iterate over `m.INDEX`, you have to pass it as data.
If you want to generate `tr` and `td`, you should read a little bit about nesting: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/